# How to define a foreign key to a sub type in a TPT inheritance hierarchy

Tags: c#, .net, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm working with Entity Framework 5.0 in .NET 4.5. I'm trying to build a Table Per Type (TPT) inheritance hierarchy where I have a foreign key to the primary key of one of the sub classes. Unfortunately, Entity Framework is giving me the following compile error:

> Error 3024: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 163:Must
>   specify mapping for all key properties (Id) of End Derived1 in
>   Relationship FK_Items_Derived1.

I created a test database and EF model to show demonstrate the model. My database model looks like this:

[image]

To create the Entity Framework model I:

- added these tables to the Entity Framework designer;
- selected `Base` as base type on `Derived1` and `Derived2`;
- removed the foreign key relationship between `Derived1` and `Base` and
  between `Derived2` and `Base` (since there's now a inheritance relationship);
- I removed the `Id` properties from `Derived1` and `Derived2` (since they inherit the `Id` property from `Base`).

This resulted is the following model:

[image]

Now when I compile it, Entity Framework prompts me with the previously stated compile error:

> Error 3024: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 163:Must
>   specify mapping for all key properties (Id) of End Derived1 in
>   Relationship FK_Items_Derived1.

The error seems to be pointing at the following line in the Model's XML mapping:

```xml
<AssociationSetMapping Name="FK_Items_Derived1" 
    TypeName="TestModel.FK_Items_Derived1" StoreEntitySet="Items">
    <EndProperty Name="Items">
        <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="Id" />
    </EndProperty>
</AssociationSetMapping>
```

I obviously don't want the `Items` to be mapped to the `Base` class, since only `Derived1` has items, not `Derived2`. I can't understand why the Entity Framework designer can't handle this rather common use case.

**So the question of course is how to fix this?**

To be complete, here's the complete Entity Framework mapping file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="3.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx">
  <!-- EF Runtime content -->
  <edmx:Runtime>
    <!-- SSDL content -->
    <edmx:StorageModels>
      <Schema Namespace="TestModel.Store" Alias="Self" Provider="System.Data.SqlClient" ProviderManifestToken="2008" xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm/ssdl">
        <EntityContainer Name="TestModelStoreContainer">
          <EntitySet Name="Base" EntityType="TestModel.Store.Base" store:Type="Tables" Schema="dbo" />
          <EntitySet Name="Derived1" EntityType="TestModel.Store.Derived1" store:Type="Tables" Schema="dbo" />
          <EntitySet Name="Derived2" EntityType="TestModel.Store.Derived2" store:Type="Tables" Schema="dbo" />
          <EntitySet Name="Items" EntityType="TestModel.Store.Items" store:Type="Tables" Schema="dbo" />
          <AssociationSet Name="FK_Derived1_Base" Association="TestModel.Store.FK_Derived1_Base">
            <End Role="Base" EntitySet="Base" />
            <End Role="Derived1" EntitySet="Derived1" />
          </AssociationSet>
          <AssociationSet Name="FK_Derived2_Base" Association="TestModel.Store.FK_Derived2_Base">
            <End Role="Base" EntitySet="Base" />
            <End Role="Derived2" EntitySet="Derived2" />
          </AssociationSet>
          <AssociationSet Name="FK_Items_Derived1" Association="TestModel.Store.FK_Items_Derived1">
            <End Role="Derived1" EntitySet="Derived1" />
            <End Role="Items" EntitySet="Items" />
          </AssociationSet>
        </EntityContainer>
        <EntityType Name="Base">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="Id" Type="uniqueidentifier" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Name" Type="nvarchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="50" />
        </EntityType>
        <EntityType Name="Derived1">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="Id" Type="uniqueidentifier" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Length" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
        </EntityType>
        <EntityType Name="Derived2">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="Id" Type="uniqueidentifier" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Size" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
        </EntityType>
        <EntityType Name="Items">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="Id" Type="uniqueidentifier" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Derived1Id" Type="uniqueidentifier" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Description" Type="nvarchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="50" />
        </EntityType>
        <Association Name="FK_Derived1_Base">
          <End Role="Base" Type="TestModel.Store.Base" Multiplicity="1" />
          <End Role="Derived1" Type="TestModel.Store.Derived1" Multiplicity="0..1" />
          <ReferentialConstraint>
            <Principal Role="Base">
              <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
            </Principal>
            <Dependent Role="Derived1">
              <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
            </Dependent>
          </ReferentialConstraint>
        </Association>
        <Association Name="FK_Derived2_Base">
          <End Role="Base" Type="TestModel.Store.Base" Multiplicity="1" />
          <End Role="Derived2" Type="TestModel.Store.Derived2" Multiplicity="0..1" />
          <ReferentialConstraint>
            <Principal Role="Base">
              <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
            </Principal>
            <Dependent Role="Derived2">
              <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
            </Dependent>
          </ReferentialConstraint>
        </Association>
        <Association Name="FK_Items_Derived1">
          <End Role="Derived1" Type="TestModel.Store.Derived1" Multiplicity="1" />
          <End Role="Items" Type="TestModel.Store.Items" Multiplicity="*" />
          <ReferentialConstraint>
            <Principal Role="Derived1">
              <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
            </Principal>
            <Dependent Role="Items">
              <PropertyRef Name="Derived1Id" />
            </Dependent>
          </ReferentialConstraint>
        </Association>
      </Schema>
    </edmx:StorageModels>
    <!-- CSDL content -->
    <edmx:ConceptualModels>
      <Schema Namespace="TestModel" Alias="Self" p1:UseStrongSpatialTypes="false" xmlns:annotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation" xmlns:p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm">
        <EntityContainer Name="Entities" p1:LazyLoadingEnabled="true">
          <EntitySet Name="Base" EntityType="TestModel.Base" />
          <EntitySet Name="Items" EntityType="TestModel.Items" />
          <AssociationSet Name="FK_Items_Derived1" Association="TestModel.FK_Items_Derived1">
            <End Role="Derived1" EntitySet="Base" />
            <End Role="Items" EntitySet="Items" />
          </AssociationSet>
        </EntityContainer>
        <EntityType Name="Base">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="Id" Type="Guid" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Name" Type="String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="50" Unicode="true" FixedLength="false" />
        </EntityType>
        <EntityType Name="Derived1" BaseType="TestModel.Base">
          <Property Name="Length" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" />
          <NavigationProperty Name="Items" Relationship="TestModel.FK_Items_Derived1" FromRole="Derived1" ToRole="Items" />
        </EntityType>
        <EntityType Name="Derived2" BaseType="TestModel.Base">
          <Property Name="Size" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" />
        </EntityType>
        <EntityType Name="Items">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="Id" Type="Guid" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Description" Type="String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="50" Unicode="true" FixedLength="false" />
          <NavigationProperty Name="Derived1" Relationship="TestModel.FK_Items_Derived1" FromRole="Items" ToRole="Derived1" />
        </EntityType>
        <Association Name="FK_Items_Derived1">
          <End Role="Derived1" Type="TestModel.Derived1" Multiplicity="1" />
          <End Role="Items" Type="TestModel.Items" Multiplicity="*" />
        </Association>
      </Schema>
    </edmx:ConceptualModels>
    <!-- C-S mapping content -->
    <edmx:Mappings>
      <Mapping Space="C-S" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/mapping/cs">
        <EntityContainerMapping StorageEntityContainer="TestModelStoreContainer" CdmEntityContainer="Entities">
          <EntitySetMapping Name="Base">
            <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="IsTypeOf(TestModel.Base)">
              <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="Base">
                <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="Id" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="Name" ColumnName="Name" />
              </MappingFragment>
            </EntityTypeMapping>
            <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="IsTypeOf(TestModel.Derived2)">
              <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="Derived2">
                <ScalarProperty Name="Size" ColumnName="Size" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="Id" />
              </MappingFragment>
            </EntityTypeMapping>
            <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="IsTypeOf(TestModel.Derived1)">
              <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="Derived1">
                <ScalarProperty Name="Length" ColumnName="Length" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="Id" />
              </MappingFragment>
            </EntityTypeMapping>
          </EntitySetMapping>
          <EntitySetMapping Name="Items">
            <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="TestModel.Items">
              <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="Items">
                <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="Id" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="Description" ColumnName="Description" />
              </MappingFragment>
            </EntityTypeMapping>
          </EntitySetMapping>
          <AssociationSetMapping Name="FK_Items_Derived1" TypeName="TestModel.FK_Items_Derived1" StoreEntitySet="Items">
            <EndProperty Name="Items">
              <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="Id" />
            </EndProperty>
          </AssociationSetMapping>
        </EntityContainerMapping>
      </Mapping>
    </edmx:Mappings>
  </edmx:Runtime>
  <!-- EF Designer content (DO NOT EDIT MANUALLY BELOW HERE) -->
  <Designer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx">
    <Connection>
      <DesignerInfoPropertySet>
        <DesignerProperty Name="MetadataArtifactProcessing" Value="EmbedInOutputAssembly" />
      </DesignerInfoPropertySet>
    </Connection>
    <Options>
      <DesignerInfoPropertySet>
        <DesignerProperty Name="ValidateOnBuild" Value="true" />
        <DesignerProperty Name="EnablePluralization" Value="False" />
        <DesignerProperty Name="IncludeForeignKeysInModel" Value="False" />
        <DesignerProperty Name="CodeGenerationStrategy" Value="None" />
      </DesignerInfoPropertySet>
    </Options>
    <!-- Diagram content (shape and connector positions) -->
    <Diagrams></Diagrams>
  </Designer>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

And for anyone who wants to reproduce this locally, here are the DDL scripts:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Base](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Base] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
 WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
 ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Derived1](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Length] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Derived1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC) 
 WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
 ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Derived2](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Size] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Derived2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
 WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
 ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Items](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Derived1Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Items] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
 WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
 ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Derived1]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Derived1_Base] FOREIGN KEY([Id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Base] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Derived1] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Derived1_Base]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Derived2]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Derived2_Base] FOREIGN KEY([Id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Base] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Derived2] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Derived2_Base]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Items]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Items_Derived1] FOREIGN KEY([Derived1Id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Derived1] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Items] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Items_Derived1]
GO
```

Comment: This seems to be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783117/entityframework-mappings-what-is-wrong-with-this-mapping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jdev4ls pointed me at the answer. By removing the primary key from the model (from `Derived1`), the Entity Framework is missing some information to make the assosiation. It's unclear to me how I could have prevented this, and I believe that the designer should make this much simpler, since this is IMO a very common use case

But nonetheless, you can either update the XML or do this in the designer. With the example above, go search for the following XML:

```
<AssociationSetMapping Name="FK_Items_Derived1"
    TypeName="tempdatabase1Model1.FK_Items_Derived1" StoreEntitySet="Items">
    <EndProperty Name="Items">
        <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="Id" />
    </EndProperty>
</AssociationSetMapping>
```

And add an `EndProperty` for `Derived` with a `ScalarProperty` to point at `Derived1Id` like this:

```
<AssociationSetMapping Name="FK_Items_Derived1" 
    TypeName="tempdatabase1Model1.FK_Items_Derived1" StoreEntitySet="Items">
    <EndProperty Name="Derived1">
        <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="Derived1Id" />
    </EndProperty>
    <EndProperty Name="Items">
        <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="Id" />
    </EndProperty>
</AssociationSetMapping>
```

If you rather want to do this using the designer (as I do), do the following:

- Right click on the relationship between `Items` and `Derived1`.
- Select 'Table Mapping' in the context menu.
- The Mapping Details for this association will show and you'll see right away that one of the Columns is missing. You can pick the `Derived1Id uniqueidentifier` from the dropdown list and you're done.
- Note that if the `Derive1` entity has foreign key properties of its own, you might need t fix them as well, but Entity Framework seems to swap the columns. After filling in the missing column, you might have to swap the two columns.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the model configuration working with TPT mapping.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="3.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx">
  <!-- EF Runtime content -->
  <edmx:Runtime>
    <!-- SSDL content -->
    <edmx:StorageModels>
      <Schema Namespace="tempdatabase1Model1.Store" Provider="System.Data.SqlClient" ProviderManifestToken="2008" Alias="Self" xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm/ssdl">
        <EntityType Name="Base">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="Id" Type="uniqueidentifier" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Name" Type="nvarchar" MaxLength="50" Nullable="false" />
        </EntityType>
        <EntityType Name="Derived1">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="Id" Type="uniqueidentifier" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Length" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
        </EntityType>
        <EntityType Name="Derived2">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="Id" Type="uniqueidentifier" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Size" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
        </EntityType>
        <EntityType Name="Items">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="Id" Type="uniqueidentifier" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Derived1Id" Type="uniqueidentifier" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Description" Type="nvarchar" MaxLength="50" Nullable="false" />
        </EntityType>
        <Association Name="FK_Derived1_Base">
          <End Role="Base" Type="Self.Base" Multiplicity="1" />
          <End Role="Derived1" Type="Self.Derived1" Multiplicity="0..1" />
          <ReferentialConstraint>
            <Principal Role="Base">
              <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
            </Principal>
            <Dependent Role="Derived1">
              <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
            </Dependent>
          </ReferentialConstraint>
        </Association>
        <Association Name="FK_Derived2_Base">
          <End Role="Base" Type="Self.Base" Multiplicity="1" />
          <End Role="Derived2" Type="Self.Derived2" Multiplicity="0..1" />
          <ReferentialConstraint>
            <Principal Role="Base">
              <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
            </Principal>
            <Dependent Role="Derived2">
              <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
            </Dependent>
          </ReferentialConstraint>
        </Association>
        <Association Name="FK_Items_Derived1">
          <End Role="Derived1" Type="Self.Derived1" Multiplicity="1" />
          <End Role="Items" Type="Self.Items" Multiplicity="*" />
          <ReferentialConstraint>
            <Principal Role="Derived1">
              <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
            </Principal>
            <Dependent Role="Items">
              <PropertyRef Name="Derived1Id" />
            </Dependent>
          </ReferentialConstraint>
        </Association>
        <EntityContainer Name="tempdatabase1Model1StoreContainer">
          <EntitySet Name="Base" EntityType="Self.Base" Schema="dbo" store:Type="Tables" />
          <EntitySet Name="Derived1" EntityType="Self.Derived1" Schema="dbo" store:Type="Tables" />
          <EntitySet Name="Derived2" EntityType="Self.Derived2" Schema="dbo" store:Type="Tables" />
          <EntitySet Name="Items" EntityType="Self.Items" Schema="dbo" store:Type="Tables" />
          <AssociationSet Name="FK_Derived1_Base" Association="Self.FK_Derived1_Base">
            <End Role="Base" EntitySet="Base" />
            <End Role="Derived1" EntitySet="Derived1" />
          </AssociationSet>
          <AssociationSet Name="FK_Derived2_Base" Association="Self.FK_Derived2_Base">
            <End Role="Base" EntitySet="Base" />
            <End Role="Derived2" EntitySet="Derived2" />
          </AssociationSet>
          <AssociationSet Name="FK_Items_Derived1" Association="Self.FK_Items_Derived1">
            <End Role="Derived1" EntitySet="Derived1" />
            <End Role="Items" EntitySet="Items" />
          </AssociationSet>
        </EntityContainer>
      </Schema>
    </edmx:StorageModels>
    <!-- CSDL content -->
    <edmx:ConceptualModels>
      <Schema Namespace="tempdatabase1Model1" Alias="Self" annotation:UseStrongSpatialTypes="false" xmlns:annotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm">
        <EntityType Name="Base">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="Id" Type="Guid" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Name" Type="String" MaxLength="50" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" Nullable="false" />
        </EntityType>
        <EntityType Name="Derived1" BaseType="tempdatabase1Model1.Base">
          <Property Name="Length" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" />
          <NavigationProperty Name="Items" Relationship="Self.FK_Items_Derived1" FromRole="Derived1" ToRole="Items" />
        </EntityType>
        <EntityType Name="Derived2" BaseType="tempdatabase1Model1.Base">
          <Property Name="Size" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" />
        </EntityType>
        <EntityType Name="Item">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="Id" Type="Guid" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Description" Type="String" MaxLength="50" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" Nullable="false" />
          <NavigationProperty Name="Derived1" Relationship="Self.FK_Items_Derived1" FromRole="Items" ToRole="Derived1" />
        </EntityType>
        <Association Name="FK_Derived1_Base">
          <End Role="Base" Type="Self.Base" Multiplicity="1" />
          <End Role="Derived1" Type="Self.Derived1" Multiplicity="0..1" />
          <ReferentialConstraint>
            <Principal Role="Base">
              <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
            </Principal>
            <Dependent Role="Derived1">
              <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
            </Dependent>
          </ReferentialConstraint>
        </Association>
        <Association Name="FK_Derived2_Base">
          <End Role="Base" Type="Self.Base" Multiplicity="1" />
          <End Role="Derived2" Type="Self.Derived2" Multiplicity="0..1" />
          <ReferentialConstraint>
            <Principal Role="Base">
              <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
            </Principal>
            <Dependent Role="Derived2">
              <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
            </Dependent>
          </ReferentialConstraint>
        </Association>
        <Association Name="FK_Items_Derived1">
          <End Role="Derived1" Type="Self.Derived1" Multiplicity="1" />
          <End Role="Items" Type="Self.Item" Multiplicity="*" />
        </Association>
        <EntityContainer Name="tempdatabase1Entities1" annotation:LazyLoadingEnabled="true">
          <EntitySet Name="Bases" EntityType="Self.Base" />
          <EntitySet Name="Items" EntityType="Self.Item" />
          <AssociationSet Name="FK_Derived1_Base" Association="Self.FK_Derived1_Base">
            <End Role="Base" EntitySet="Bases" />
            <End Role="Derived1" EntitySet="Bases" />
          </AssociationSet>
          <AssociationSet Name="FK_Derived2_Base" Association="Self.FK_Derived2_Base">
            <End Role="Base" EntitySet="Bases" />
            <End Role="Derived2" EntitySet="Bases" />
          </AssociationSet>
          <AssociationSet Name="FK_Items_Derived1" Association="Self.FK_Items_Derived1">
            <End Role="Derived1" EntitySet="Bases" />
            <End Role="Items" EntitySet="Items" />
          </AssociationSet>
        </EntityContainer>
      </Schema>
    </edmx:ConceptualModels>
    <!-- C-S mapping content -->
    <edmx:Mappings>
      <Mapping Space="C-S" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/mapping/cs">
        <EntityContainerMapping StorageEntityContainer="tempdatabase1Model1StoreContainer" CdmEntityContainer="tempdatabase1Entities1">
          <EntitySetMapping Name="Bases">
            <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="IsTypeOf(tempdatabase1Model1.Base)">
              <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="Base">
                <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="Id" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="Name" ColumnName="Name" />
              </MappingFragment>
            </EntityTypeMapping>
            <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="IsTypeOf(tempdatabase1Model1.Derived1)">
              <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="Derived1">
                <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="Id" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="Length" ColumnName="Length" />
              </MappingFragment>
            </EntityTypeMapping>
            <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="IsTypeOf(tempdatabase1Model1.Derived2)">
              <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="Derived2">
                <ScalarProperty Name="Size" ColumnName="Size" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="Id" />
              </MappingFragment>
            </EntityTypeMapping>
          </EntitySetMapping>
          <EntitySetMapping Name="Items">
            <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="tempdatabase1Model1.Item">
              <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="Items">
                <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="Id" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="Description" ColumnName="Description" />
              </MappingFragment>
            </EntityTypeMapping>
          </EntitySetMapping>
          <AssociationSetMapping Name="FK_Items_Derived1" TypeName="tempdatabase1Model1.FK_Items_Derived1" StoreEntitySet="Items">
            <EndProperty Name="Derived1">
              <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="Derived1Id" />
            </EndProperty>
            <EndProperty Name="Items">
              <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="Id" />
            </EndProperty>
          </AssociationSetMapping>
        </EntityContainerMapping>
      </Mapping>
    </edmx:Mappings>
  </edmx:Runtime>
  <!-- EF Designer content (DO NOT EDIT MANUALLY BELOW HERE) -->
  <Designer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx">
    <Connection>
      <DesignerInfoPropertySet>
        <DesignerProperty Name="MetadataArtifactProcessing" Value="EmbedInOutputAssembly" />
      </DesignerInfoPropertySet>
    </Connection>
    <Options>
      <DesignerInfoPropertySet>
        <DesignerProperty Name="ValidateOnBuild" Value="true" />
        <DesignerProperty Name="EnablePluralization" Value="true" />
        <DesignerProperty Name="IncludeForeignKeysInModel" Value="false" />
        <DesignerProperty Name="UseLegacyProvider" Value="true" />
        <DesignerProperty Name="CodeGenerationStrategy" Value="None" />
      </DesignerInfoPropertySet>
    </Options>
    <!-- Diagram content (shape and connector positions) -->
    <Diagrams></Diagrams>
  </Designer>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

Answer (score 1):

An entity framework code first solution for what it is worth.

See full blog post here:
http://jnye.co/Posts/18/table-per-type-tpt-database-using-entityframework-code-first

**The models**

```
public abstract class BaseTable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Table("DerivedWithRelation")]
public class DerivedWithRelation : BaseTable
{
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public string About { get; set; }
    public int RelatedId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Relation> Relations { get; set; }
}

[Table("DerivedWithoutRelation")]
public class DerivedWithoutRelation : BaseTable
{
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Relation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RelationshipType { get; set; }

    public virtual DerivedWithRelation DerivedWithRelation { get; set; }
}
```

**The context**

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {            
    }
    
    public IDbSet<BaseTable> BaseTables { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<DerivedWithRelation> DerivedWithRelations { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<DerivedWithoutRelation> DerivedWithoutRelations { get; set; }
}
```

[image: Schema created using Entity Framework code first and TPT]
<sub>(source: [jnye.co](http://jnye.co/Content/Images/Demo/EntityFrameworkCodeFirstTPT.png))</sub>

Hope that helps.